# How to use context in Kotlin classes on Android

Tags: android, kotlin

In my application i have use **Retrofit** and **okHttpClient** for get some request to server.
In this **retrofit** config i want send some data into `Header` to server.
This data is **device UUID** and for get **device UUID** i write below code in one class (this class name is Extensions) :

```
@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
fun Context.getDeviceUUID(): String {
    return try {
        Settings.Secure.getString(contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        "exception"
    }
}
```

For get **device UUID** i should pass `context`.

And i want send this **device UUID** into **ApiClient** class.
**ApiClient class :**

```
class ApiClient {

    private val apiServices: ApiServices

    init {
        //Gson
        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()

        //Http log
        val loggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        loggingInterceptor.level =
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY else HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.NONE

        //Http Builder
        val clientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        clientBuilder.interceptors().add(loggingInterceptor)
        clientBuilder.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val request = chain.request()
            request.newBuilder().addHeader("uuid", ).build()
            chain.proceed(request)
        }

        //Http client
        val client = clientBuilder
            .readTimeout(NETWORK_CONNECTIONS_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(NETWORK_CONNECTIONS_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(NETWORK_CONNECTIONS_TIME, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .build()

        //Retrofit
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
            .build()

        //Init apiServices
        apiServices = retrofit.create(ApiServices::class.java)
    }

    companion object {
        private var apiClient: ApiClient? = null

        val instance: ApiClient
            get() {
                if (apiClient == null) {
                    apiClient = ApiClient()
                }
                return apiClient as ApiClient
            }
    }
}
```

I should use **getDeviceUUID** in this code : `request.newBuilder().addHeader("uuid", ).build()`

how can i pass `context` into **ApiClient** class ?

Comment: Why don't just pass device id to `ApiClient` constructor instead passing `Context`..

Comment: @ADM, thanks dear but how can i it? because i should pass this constructor in this code : `apiClient = ApiClient()`

Comment: Create Constructor `class ApiClient(val deviceId:String)` And Use `deviceId` inside `ApiClient`.

Comment: @ADM, yes my friend but not found deviceId! in write this code : `class ApiClient constructor(private val deviceUUID: String)` but in this code : `apiClient = ApiClient()` not found **deviceUUID** !!!  why not found ?!

Comment: @ADM , do you have free time for help me? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify `ApiClient` have a constructor and a parameter in `get()`.

```
class APiClient(var deviceId: String) {
init {
    //Stuff goes here
}
companion object {
    private var apiClient: APiClient? = null
    fun getInstance(deviceId: String): APiClient =
            apiClient ?: synchronized(this) {
                apiClient ?: APiClient(deviceId).also {
                    apiClient = it
                }
            }
}
}
```

PS, `deviceUUID` can be Global cause it will not change. A better approach will be just  let it be in Global Access like in Application class . From where you can directly use it . No need to pass it in constructor each time .